# SQL query not returning the expected result

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables `events` and `beschikbaar`. In the table `beschikbaar` I store the `eventid` and `userid` for users that make themselves available for a particular event.

I want to have a selection with all events from the event table, except the ones that are listed in the beschikbaar table for the current user.

This is my sql :

```
SELECT events.id, events.title, events.start, events.end, beschikbaar.userID,beschikbaar.eventID 
FROM events 
LEFT JOIN beschikbaar ON events.id = beschikbaar.eventID 
WHERE beschikbaar.userID <> 6 OR beschikbaar.eventID IS NULL
```

The problem that I have now is that when another user makes himself available for the same event, it still is in the list.

Included you find a screenshot of the two tables:

[image: detail of two tables]

As you can see the event 'mamba open air' and 'great gigs in the park' still appears in the left table because a other user has selected this.

Anyone knows how to make my query handle this?

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Please don't add "SOLVED" mark the answer that solved your issue by pressing the green tick next to it

Answer (score 0):

You want to move the condition to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT e.id, e.title, e.start, e.end, b.userID, b.eventID 
FROM events e left join
     beschikbaar b
     on e.id = b.eventID and b.userID = 6
WHERE b.eventID is null;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution Gordon, this does the job!

Comment: @StevenMees accept the answer if solves the problem :)